# Should I use a gobal variable? If not, how do I solve it?

Tags: java, global-variables

I've just started learning Java, and have some trouble dealing with scope of variables.

```
public static void updateBoard(String[][] gameBoard, int gameTurn, int[] coords) {
    int userRow = coords[0];
    int userColumn = coords[1];
    int realRow;
    int realColumn;

    // Convert user rows and columns to actual indexes in board-matrix
    switch (userRow) {
    case 0: realRow = 1; break;
    case 1: realRow = 3; break;
    case 2: realRow = 5; break;
    }

    switch (userColumn) {
    case 0: realColumn = 2; break;
    case 1: realColumn = 6; break;
    case 2: realColumn = 10; break;
    }

    if (gameTurn % 2 == 0) 
        java.util.Arrays.fill(gameBoard[realRow], realColumn, realColumn + 1, "X");
    else
        java.util.Arrays.fill(gameBoard[realRow], realColumn, realColumn + 1, "O");
```

So the realRow and realColumn variables in the if-statement are not initialized. I haven't learned about global variables yet. I'm clueless atm on how to solve this without using the variables inside the switch statements. Any ideas on how to solve this?
Btw this is for a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Comment: There is no such thing as a global variable in Java

Comment: oh! really? global variable in java

Comment: When using switch, make specifying a default case (`default:`) a habit. Assign to your variables there or throw an exception.

Comment: I see. So I can solve it by either initializing 'int realRow = 0;' or by providing a default case. But as you say, default case is a good habit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if `userRow` is not 0, 1 or 2, `realRow` will not be initialized.

You need to either give it a default value:

```
int realRow = 0;
```

Or supply a `default` for the switch:

```
switch (userRow) {
    case 0: realRow = 1; break;
    case 1: realRow = 3; break;
    case 2: realRow = 5; break;
    default: realRow = 0;
}
```

For the above solutions, 0 (or some other chosen value) **must be an acceptable value for `realRow` to have**.

If this is not true, you should consider throwing an exception in `default:` instead.

Or, if you're assured that `userRow` is always 0, 1 or 2 (or you're happy defaulting to one of the cases), you can make one of the cases default instead:

```
switch (userRow) {
    case 0: realRow = 1; break;
    case 1: realRow = 3; break;
    default: realRow = 5; // case 2
}
```

And the same for `realColumn`.

Comment: I'm sure they're always 0, 1 or 2 because I test for them elsewhere. But I can see using 'default: ' is a good habit. Thanks for the good explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide values for both of them. For example:

```
int realRow = 0; 
int realColumn = 0;
```

If you declare the variable as class members, they will have default values of `0`. For example, the member fiels for this class will have default value of `0`:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int realRow;
    private int realColumn;
}
```

Consider the case, in which the `switch` statement doesn't provide the variables with values. In this case, you should use a `default` statement within the `switch`, in order to initialize the variables correctly.

```
switch (userColumn) {
    case 0: realColumn = 2; break;
    case 1: realColumn = 6; break;
    case 2: realColumn = 10; break;
    default: realColumn = 0; //for example
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it :) I'm sure why though. Is it just in case the switch-statements should fail to give them values?

Comment: If you never assign bogus values to variables then you won't have to track down bugs related to bogus values in variables.  It's better off to raise an exception in the `default` case.

Comment: If the `case` statements fail to give them values, you should have it in mind and use a `default` statement (where a default value will be applied).

Answer (score 0):

Add a default case to the switch statements so that the variable is always given a value, even if you get incorrect input. For example:

```
switch (userColumn) {
case 0: realColumn = 2; break;
case 1: realColumn = 6; break;
case 2: realColumn = 10; break;
default: realColumn = -1;
}
```

An alternative is giving a  default value when you declare the variable as in

```
int realColumn = 0;
```

but I wouldn't recommend it because  then the compiler can't warn you if you use the variable before any real value has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If the only valid values of `userRow` and `userColumn` are (0,1,2) then you need a `default` case that fails when they are not.

```
switch (userRow) {
case 0: realRow = 1; break;
case 1: realRow = 3; break;
case 2: realRow = 5; break;
default:
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "userRow must be in [0-2], not " + userRow);
}
```

Now, `realRow` will never reach the end of the `switch` without being initialized, so can be used later.

You can always move the row and column translation code into separate methods to make it clearer what has been initialized

```
   int realRow = userRowToRealRow(userRow);

   ...

private static int userRowToRealRow(int userRow) {
  switch (userRow) {
    case 0: return 1;
    case 1: return 3;
    case 2: return 5;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "userRow must be in [0-2], not " + userRow);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that represents your gameboard.  It would have *instance* variables -- their scope is the entire class, not one method in the class -- that represent the current state of the board.  Have a method in that class that updates the game board -- it can take, as parameters, the row and column of the move and whether it is x or o.

This method could return a state -- game won, game not finished, illegal move if you haven't validated that already.

Comment: This, my answer, is really about "how could I do this without 'global' variables, rather than how to fix anything about the given code.  Am not sure (now) if you were looking for a different way of doing things than fixing problems with this one.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a matter of variable scope.You search only for the case of 1 2 3.What if there is a different value?You must add a default case.